# Gnuplot: How to add a non-number value on y-axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data like this:

```
# Time    Index Value
 46.4727    7   1
 49.0155    8   1
 54.1011    10  F
 56.8156    11  F
 67.1116    15  0.647708
  69.748    16  0.68048
 72.2441    17  0.703938
```

where my values can be any number between `[0,1]` plus "F". I have tried simply:

```
plot data 1:3
```

but the "F" values are not shown. How can I add a new value "F" on y-axis below 0? I want to plot exactly like I only have values between 0 and 1, except that I also want to take into account the new value "F" on my data, and show it on the diagram.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

```
Fval=-1
set ytics 0,0.1,1; 
set ytics add ("F" Fval);
plot 'test.txt' u 1:(strcol(3) eq 'F'?Fval:$3)
```

Basically you decide the value to give to the "F" values, then constrain ytics betwwen [0:1], you add a tick on the `Y` axe at `Fval` value, and filter "F" values to be plotted at `Fval`.

Comment: I would recommend a slightly different approach to add the axis tics.  Instead of the label, do `set ytics 0,0.1,1; set ytics add ("F" Fval);`.  This will set the ytics between 0 and 1 as you have done, but add an additional tic mark labeled _F_ at the Fval.  Doing it this way it will be a normal tic mark, and not a label (which can sometimes be challenging to get it exactly where you want it).

Comment: you're right! I wasn't aware of the `tics add` ! I edited the answer accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Thank you guys! That was helpful.